# How to setup PCL in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, openni, point-cloud-library

I saw some posts telling that PCL won't work with visualStudio 12 and soemsaying that we need to install and cmake stuff.

**Questions**

1) will latest PCL Library work with visual Studio ??

2) Will All-in-one installer do all the work or do we need to cmake stuff ??

3) We already have OpenNI latest version installed in our system. will it cause any troubles ?

4) What all stuff we need to include in the visual studio to work with PCL Library ?

Comment: I haven't use pcl with visual studio, but I recommend you to ask also in the users mailing list, they may help you faster.... [here is the link](http://pointclouds.org/contact.html)

Comment: hai @api55 i had some questions my email ashokvarmavit@gmail.com can you jst ping me. i will send you those questions thankyou for the help

Comment: @api55 PCL is having problems in VisualStudio 2012 can you post Answer with OpenGL in this Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270544/how-to-display-a-3d-image-when-we-have-depth-and-rgb-mats-in-opencv-captured-f

Comment: I sent you an email, maybe it went to spam. I think my email is on my profile....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use PCL 1.7.2, Kinect SDK 2 and OpenCV2.4.9 in VS2012.
My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514762/point-cloud-library-on-visual-studio/29874373#29874373) may help you.

Comment: once all-in-one is installed. which steps you followed for integrating it with visual studio. All the includes and all

Comment: well, I have a example project(use all-in-one PCL1.7.2 and OpenCV2.4.9) in VS2012 [download](http://acgnew.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/example_pcl1.7.2_vs2012_opencv2.4.9.zip). You can open the project and change a few place in the project property to you PCL path and OpenCV path. Also you can open it in VS2013. If you don't need opencv, just remove it from project property. I hope this will help you.